# what is the optimal way to refine a very large JSONl Data Set

Tags: python, json, parsing

My Dataset is basically a 14 Gb .jsonl file that contains recorded lightning strokes around the world. What I want to do is refine this dataset, so that only the lightning strokes that occurred in a particular country remain. The file has the following structure:

```
"strokes":[
{
"time":1627307177762,
"lat":15.377181,
"lon":-96.372142,
...
*other irrelevant data*
},
```

My question would be, what is the optimal way of achieving this task without iterating through the entire file (12 Million lines ) and checking whether a particular lightning strike has been recorded in a particular country or not. This is what my actual code does:

```
with open('file_name.jsonl') as file:
   for line in file:
      strokes = json.loads(line)['strokes']
      for strike in strokes:
         strike_location = (strike['lat'], strike['lon'])
         if reverse_geocoder.search(strike_location)[0]['cc'] == 'DE': #check whether the
                                                               #lightning strike has been
                                                              #recorded in germany or not
              strokes_DE_file.write('{}\n'.format(strike))#write to a file that will only
                                                          #contain lightning strokes 
                                                          #that occurred in germany
```

Comment: You do have to process the data at least once. There are databases like mongodb, redis, couch, etc... that can help by doing much of the work for you. You load the entire json then either write queries or implement map/reduce algorithms that generate the information. This has a learning curve!

Comment: @rv.kvetch, it is not possible to load the entire file at once, like I said, it is 14 Gb big, if i load it, the program just stops.

Comment: The data you show and the code to read it are quite different. The data isn't json, likely its a fragment. The code expects a full json record for each line. Assuming the code is correct, its already a reasonable way to filter the data set.

Comment: Is the file one single JSON document or is it a bunch of JSON, each line terminated?

Comment: @YassineElBaaj you should probably also mention and/or tag JSONL if it's in json-lines format, rather than normal JSON.

Comment: If you need to do this more than once, rewrite each json record with the geocoder resolved country info, so that you don't need to do that lift again.

Comment: @tdelaney, the file has the .jsonl extension. Reasonable way to filter the data maybe, the program has been running for 2 hours now.

Comment: @tdelaney, do you think we can continue this in private discussion room ?

Comment: Guess you can by clicking on this link, note sure if this is going to work : https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131628/room-for-yassine-el-baaj-and-tdelaney

Comment: My guess is that the slowness is the result of whatever reverse geocoding service you are using, which might also be rate-limiting you. Parsing a 14gb file with the json module might take a few minutes; I certainly wouldn't expect it to be instantaneous, but not hours.